# Tangent plane to a parametric curve

Tags: calculus, geometry, differential-geometry, 3d, tangent-line

> Find the tangent plane to a parametric curve $$\vec r(u) = x(u)\mathbf i + y(u)\mathbf j + z(u)\mathbf k$$

I know that the tangent **line** at a point $u = u_0$ is given by
$$\vec \ell(t) = \vec r(u_0) + \vec r'(u_0)(t - u_0)$$
but what about the **plane**, though?

Comment: Do you mean the [osculating plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osculating_plane)?

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland Actually, I'm a self-learner and don't know what the problem menas really. How to find the equation of osculating plane then?

Comment: It says in the link that it's the span of the tangent and normal, do you know how to find the normal?

Comment: Are you sure it is asking tangent plane? If I read the question, it says "Find the tangent to a parametric curve". So that would mean tangent line.

Comment: @MathLover Sorry, when I edited second time I missed that part.

Comment: OK understood. In that case, the question is not very clear for me. If the question seeks us to find osculating plane, it should state that. If it seeks a plane that is orthogonal to the plane that the curve resides in and also contains the tangent line, it should again state that. Otherwise we have infinite number of planes that contain the tangent line.

Comment: @MathLover This is on me, I do not study math in English, this may be the reason why the question is not clear :(

Answer (score 1):

There is no tangent **plane**, just a tangent **line**. The reason is that the your curve is a 1-dimensional manifold and the tangent space has the same dimension as the manifold.

Intuitively, a tangent vector $v$ represents the speed and direction of a body moving on the manifold while remaining "on" that manifold. For example, if you're walking on earth while remaining with your feet on the ground, you can only move tangent to the ground. In your case you have a curve, which is like a path, so you can only move forward or backward with different speeds, so the tangent space is a line.

Answer (score 1):

You have one input, so you can imagine a whole number line of all the inputs, each of which has one corresponding (3-dimensional) output. Now imagine all of the possible inputs going to their outputs, i.e. imagine that number line moving to become some other line in 3-dimensions. This is your parametric curve, the set of all possible outputs as you range the input.

Notice, your parametric curve is only a line (though it likely curves and bends in 3-dimensions), and not a plane, thus you can find a tangent line, but it doesn't really make sense to find a tangent plane. All possible planes that contain that line will be just touching the curve at that point (and thus tangent), and since their is no curving of a surface in other directions, there is no way to choose if any one of them is better (with a parametric *surface*, most of them will intersect the surface somewhere next to the line, and won't be tangent, so it makes sense to talk about a tangent plane).

I hope this helped!